# How to define a list of symbols as a list of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a list in Mathematica for example

```
P={1+t,1+t+t^2,1+t+t^3};
```

My question is, how I can define each element of this list be a function of `t`? Indeed I want something like this input

```
P[[1]][.2]
```

which its output is

```
1.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can do something like `p[[1]] /. t -> .2` while this is not a function, it will give the same out you are looking for.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks a lot. Put your comment as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few ways to do this. The simplest  might be

```
   p = {1 + t, 1 + t + t^2, 1 + t + t^3};
   p[[n]] /. t -> .2
```

where `n` is the index. Or you can convert the list to actual functions like this

```
p = Function[t, #] & /@ p
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can write  `p[[n]][.2]` as you wanted.

Now for example, you can evaluate all these function for at some value using

```
  p[[#]][.1] & /@ Range[Length[p]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
p[m_, t_] := Table[Sum[t^i, {i, 0, n}], {n, 1, m}];
```

Then the list of three elements you gave in your question is obtained as follows:

```
    p[3, t]

(*   {1 + t, 1 + t + t^2, 1 + t + t^2 + t^3}   *)
```

and the first term of the list is

```
p[3, 0.2][[1]]

(*  1.2   *)
```

Have fun!